# `do-release-upgrade` from `desktop` to `server`?

Tags: server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Is it possible to run a `do-release-upgrade` from a desktop install into `-m server`?

I have an NUC I kind of had to install via the GUI (and installed desktop). It's a server; I don't use the UI. Is it possible to "switch" to a server install on upgrade?

Comment: No: Switch from Desktop to Sever *before* a release-upgrade.

Comment: @user535733 Is it possible to "switch" without a full reinstall?

Comment: Depends upon how you originally installed Ubuntu...which your question is somewhat vague about. What do you hope to gain by "switching?" The inactive UI is not consuming any resources and negligible disk space. Desktop and Server use the same components, one merely lacks the GUI.

Comment: @user535733 I guess no reason, really. I was thinking for improved support with Home Assistant, but even *Ubuntu* Server is unsupported, only Debian Server is "officially" supported. And there's no path of upgrade from *Ubuntu* Server to *Debian* Server. I guess there really isn't any point....

Comment: I run HA Core in an LXD container on my Ubuntu Server. Works great. It's not supported by the HA developers, but so what?

Comment: I have HA Supervisor up, and Supervisor keeps dropping out of privilege. Trying to figure out why. It's interfering in updates. Rebooting the NUC fixes it, so it's clearly not settings. It's bugging me.

Comment: I was under the impression that there is no definition anywhere of what constitutes "Ubuntu Server", and the only reason against upgrading from a desktop to a server role is the possibility of continuing to keep (and upgrade) now-useless desktop packages. Is this incorrect?